# Geocoding Provider Error

Tags: payment-processor

Contributions have been processed correctly so far, but when clicking on continue in both Paypal and Redsys (credit card) the following error appears (both Live and Test)

**php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known**

```
Array

(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
       )

    [code] => 0
    [message] => php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => 
    [type] => PEAR_Error
    [user_info] => 
    [to_string] => [pear_error: message="php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known" code=0 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info=""]
)
```

backTrace

```
#0 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(182): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(PEAR_Error))
#2 / ...  /modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(PEAR_Error))
#3 / ...  /modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(566): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known", 0, 16, (Array:2), NULL)
#4 / ...  /modules/civicrm/packages/Net/Socket.php(156): PEAR->raiseError("php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known", 0)
#5 / ...  /modules/civicrm/packages/HTTP/Request.php(737): Net_Socket->connect("query.yahooapis.com", 80, NULL, NULL, NULL)
#6 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Geocode/Yahoo.php(127): HTTP_Request->sendRequest()
#7 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Address.php(387): CRM_Utils_Geocode_Yahoo::format((Array:13))
#8 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Address.php(144): CRM_Core_BAO_Address::fixAddress((Array:13))
#9 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Address.php(120): CRM_Core_BAO_Address::add((Array:13), TRUE)
#10 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Location.php(69): CRM_Core_BAO_Address::create((Array:34), TRUE, NULL)
#11 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php(348): CRM_Core_BAO_Location::create((Array:34), TRUE)
#12 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php(1897): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::create((Array:34))
#13 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(2066): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::createProfileContact((Array:35), (Array:14), "7327", (Array:0), NULL, "Individual", TRUE)
#14 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(594): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->processFormSubmission("7327")
#15 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(423): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->postProcess()
#16 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#17 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), "next", "Next")
#18 / ...  /modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), "next")
#19 / ...  /modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), "next")
#20 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#21 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
#22 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#23 / ...  /modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#24 / ...  /modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(454): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#25 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("contribute", "transact")
#26 / ... /web/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#27 /... /web/index.php(480): menu_execute_active_handler()
#28 {main}
```

I need help. Anyone got any ideas?

Thks

Comment: It looks like the error is to do with geocoding the submitted address rather than anything to do with the payment processor. Could you check that the geocoding is working correctly and/or turn it off and see if there is still an issue?

Answer (score 3):

Like William says, the error is due to the geocoding, which may even be happening after the contribution completes. Your system is trying to geocode with the domain http://query.yahooapis.com/ which no longer has a dns entry.

Chances are you are running a very old version of CiviCRM and need to upgrade it, but in any case, you can just remove geocoding in Administer -> System Settings -> Mapping and Geocoding, i.e. this path:

/civicrm/admin/setting/mapping?reset=1

You could install the new geocoding extension at some point, but I'd think your priority would be to get rid of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your quick response. My Geocoding Provider was Yahoo, I have changed it to Google and it has worked again. I will have to update CIVI to a more new version (4.7.4).

Thanks again!